# How to create a form that adds to list, emails, and returns to form after submission

Tags: html, forms, server-side

For my business, I require all of my customers to sign in at a kiosk at the front of the store.

I wish to do this using a web form, and with all the inputs, I hope for them to be automatically sent to a spreadsheet.

My requirements are:

1. I'd like to have a option on the form that would allow them to subscribe to our online news letter.
2. When they finally click submit, I'd like for them to receive an email saying thank you for subscribing (if they did).
3. Furthermore I would like for the form, upon submitting, to be cleared of all previous information for the next person who visits my store.

I don't know how to do this, and I was wondering if anyone could possibly give me some tips, or a good idea/direction of how I could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you're wanting to do, you need [server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) to handle the submission.

You can use a language like [PHP](http://php.net/) to handle the form submission and:

1. write the proper data to a file
2. send an email
3. reload the form for the next user

However, for step 1, you should REALLY consider using a database like [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) to store and manage your subscriptions.

### Edit:

Here's some pseudo-code to show you how the form might be submitted and handled by PHP:

## HTML:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value='' />
    <br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" value='' />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" />Sign me up for the email list.
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In!" />
</form>
```

## PHP:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $list = isset($_POST['list']) ? true : false;

    $database = New ConnectionToDatabase();
    $database->store($name, $email, $list);

    if( $list )
    {
        mail($email, "Thanks for signing up for the [storename] mailing list!", "[Your Custom Message]");
    }

    header("Location: form.html");
?>
```

Comment: alright, awesome! how long do you think it would take me to do this if i had no prior experience with either of these languages?

Comment: Both are fairly easy to pick up, but it might take a week or two for you to figure it all out by yourself.  Storing the info in a database will take some time to learn, but it will be a LOT faster than trying to write to an excel file or similar spreadsheet.  I also want to warn you that the code I posted above is TERRIBLY flawed.  You need to learn about and protect yourself against various vulnerabilities.  The biggest is usually [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Using something like the PHP PDO may help, but it will add to the learning curve.

Comment: WOW thank you so much rockerest! you've been a big help, but i have one more question: where would be a good place to start learning PHP?

Comment: @jordan Actually, this problem is a pretty good place.  It combines handling form submission, accessing a database, and sending email.  It's a pretty good problem to help you learn about the language.  To that end, you might want to start with [Zend's tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627).  If you feel like you have a great handle on the language, try learning about [PHP objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).  If you like objects, [my database class](https://github.com/rockerest/myframework/blob/master/backbone/Database.php) has really helped me with making queries.

Comment: @jordan The best way to learn is to try to do something.  Once you have a goal, you can make educated Google queries like, ["How do I handle form submission in PHP?"](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+handle+form+submission+in+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) to help you learn one step at a time.  P.S. remember to click the white checkmark next to any answer on any of your questions if you think that answer was the correct solution or helped the most.  Low accept-rates are a bad thing on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @rockerest okay i'll sign up and all of your answers have been helpful! life saver award. time to get to work

Comment: @jordan sign up for......?  github?  You don't need to.  You can download my code for free if you want.  No account necessary unless you're planning on using git to handle code versioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reset on form submission:

```
<form onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

Comment: thanks! that's great, but how can i automatically set it up so the information is automatically sent to a spreadsheet? also how can i have it so once the user submits, they receive a welcome/thank you email?

Comment: oh wow you really added to that question since it was posted. for that additional stuff I'd give a similar answer that @rockerest did. you can ask more than one question on SO ;-)

Comment: @wajiw he didn't really add anything, I just edited it to lay out the stuff he needed more clearly :)

Comment: @rockerest the entire question was re-written with the added requirements when I first posted. it was 3 sentences originally without anything describing the form itself or it's capabilities. my answer doesn't make any sense to the question anymore

Comment: Ah, I never saw it that short.  Strange that it doesn't show up in the revision list :(

Comment: no worries wajiw, i remember why you posted that, and thank you very much for helping! seems like i a long road ahead of me ...